# Bundle ID and SKU number

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm adding an iOS App to iTunes Connect, but are confused regarding the two values `Bundle ID` and `SKU Number` which I have to chose for my App.

1. When I create a new iOS project in Xcode, lets say "MyProject", it's iOS Application Identifier would be com.mycompany.MyProject. Should the iOS Application Identifier be all lower case or what are the "guidelines"? E.g. com.MyCompany.MyApplication, com.mycompany.MyApplication or com.mycompany.myapplication? What are the guidelines regarding this?
2. Should this iOS Application ID in Xcode be equal to the Bundle ID in `iTunes Connect` and `iOS Provisioning Portal`?
3. Could someone give me an example of, what the SKU Number could look like?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

SKU number is anything you'd like, for instance if your app name is "MyApp" you can use SKU "myAppV1" or anything like that. So any value is acceptable.

For App ID you need to create an App ID in the ios dev center and choose it from the drop list of iTunesConnect. Then create an AppStore provisioning profile, copy its bundle id text and replace the one in your target's info pane under the Bundle ID section. This one is case insensitive, so no problem using  com.MyCompany.MyApplication.

Comment: So I'll add a new unique SKU for each version of my App? Regarding the App ID, I'm not sure, if the `Identifier`for my Xcode project target should be equal to the Bundle ID? Currently my `Identifier` in my Xcode project is "com.MyCompany.MyProjectName" and my Bundle ID is "com.mycompany.myprojectname". Is that ok?

Comment: When in your project's build settings, select a distribution profile for Release code signing identity you've created via ios provisioning profile, if it's grayed out - your bundle id is wrong. If it is selectable, then everything's fine.

Comment: What about the SKU? Is is static or should it change for each version?

Comment: can i change the SKU number? Please Help me @Eugene

Comment: can i change the SKU number? Please Help me @Dennis Madsen

Comment: ok .. Thank u...if we want, do we need to upload again like a new project. Again from the check list preparation? i did the mistake  when uploading the app... Now my client is raising this question.. i am getting mad  @Eugene

Comment: @Babul the SKU number is you plain identifier of the project, it's not important, for instance if you have 100 applications uploaded you might want to store their profit records in a table document like .xls and have their SKU identifiers in a certain column. There's no real other use for this identifier. Tell your client that it won't affect the application from user's standpoint in any way.

Comment: ok sure i will explain to my client.. Thank u so much @Eugene

Comment: Bundle ID **is** [case-sensitive](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)

Comment: @Bigood @babul can i use my bundle id like this `com.tops.109idea`

Comment: @ilesh yes, you can use any type of string for SKU identifier